# How to use Xpath to return the content?

Tags: python, html, xpath

```
<tr>
    <td width="120" align="right" class="tit">Bank：</td>
    <td><span style="text-decoration: underline;color: #0066ff;cursor: pointer"  onclick="_search('ad','2016.11.22');">2016.11.22</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="120" align="right" class="tit">Shop：</td>
    <td>CN108084067B</td>
</tr>
```

How to use Xpath to get the name "Shop"?  I use below code which doesn't work.

```
number3 = html.xpath('//tr[contains(text(),"Bank")]/following-sibling::tr[1]/td/text()')[0]
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear: what is the basis for selecting "Shop"? Is it because it's in the second `<tr>`, the first to follow the one with "Bank", another reason?

Answer (score 0):

If it must be the one immediately following "Bank", then you can try
`'//td[contains(text(),"Bank")]//parent::tr//following-sibling::tr/td[contains(text(),"Shop")]'`

Comment: "Shop" have different values. that's why needS to base "bank" which the value doesn' t change

Answer (score 0):

In Selenium try this

`driver.find_element_by_xpath('....xpath...').get_attribute('innerHTML')`

Answer (score 0):

Just fix your XPath with :

```
//tr[contains(.,"Bank")]/following-sibling::tr[1]/td[1]/text()
```

Code :

```
data = """HTML
<table>
<tr>
    <td width="120" align="right" class="tit">Bank：</td>
    <td><span style="text-decoration: underline;color: #0066ff;cursor: pointer"  onclick="_search('ad','2016.11.22');">2016.11.22</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="120" align="right" class="tit">Shop：</td>
    <td>CN108084067B</td>
</tr>
</table>
HTML"""

import lxml.html
tree = lxml.html.fromstring(data)
print (tree.xpath('//tr[contains(.,"Bank")]/following-sibling::tr[1]/td[1]/text()'))
```

Output :

```
['Shop：']
```